# Weights&Biases Sweep - Why might runs be overwriting each other?

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, yolo

I am new to ML and W&B, and I am trying to use W&B to do a hyperparameter sweep. I created a few sweeps and when I run them I get a bunch of new runs in my project (as I would expect):
[Image: New runs being created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VhZS.png)

However, all of the new runs say "no metrics logged yet" ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/na1I4.png)) and are instead all of their metrics are going into one run (the one with the green dot in the photo above). This makes it not useable, of course, since all the metrics and images and graph data for many different runs are all being crammed into one run.

Is there anyone that has some experience in W&B? I feel like this is an issue that should be relatively straightforward to solve - like something in the W&B config that I need to change.

Any help would be appreciated. I didn't give too many details because I am hoping this is relatively straightforward, but if there are any specific questions I'd be happy to provide more info. The basics:

- Using Google Colab for training
- Project is a PyTorch-YOLOv3 object detection model that is based on this: https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov3

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I think I figured it out.

I was using the train.py code from the repository I linked in the question, and part of that code specifies the id of the run (used for resuming).

I removed the part where it specifies the ID, and it is now working :)

Old code:

```
wandb_run = wandb.init(config=opt, resume="allow",
                           project='YOLOv3' if opt.project == 'runs/train' else Path(opt.project).stem,
                           name=save_dir.stem,
                           id=ckpt.get('wandb_id') if 'ckpt' in locals() else None)
```

New code:

```
wandb_run = wandb.init(config=opt, resume="allow",
                       project='YOLOv3' if opt.project == 'runs/train' else Path(opt.project).stem,
                       name=save_dir.stem)
```